# jQuery search array via textfield

Tags: jquery, mysql, live, updating

I'm struggling to figure out how to make this work for a university project, some help would be amazing!!

Ive got a mysql database which stores lots of items. (i can do this bit no problem).

Ive got a search box which needs to search the item database as you type. (im sure you know what i mean? bit like the google instant search)

When you click the item from the list of possibles that drops down from the suggested items.
it appends a unordered list via jquery to add the item there.

however I've got no idea how to go about this.

i've made a jquery fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/OwenMelbz/QW7Bc/ of what i mean instead of pasting code here.

hope you can help.

thanks

Owen

Comment: "bit like the google instant search". it's called auto-completion. there is about two dozen gazillions jquery plugins specialized in this enhancing of our user laziness. But thanx for fiddle :)

Comment: Do you have to pull the data out as the user types or can you send all the data that you think you will need to the page and store it in a javascript object and pull it from the object when needed?

Comment: everything is possible, with cache strategies. I usually pull the data at each keypress, mainly beaucause my user like, when the type "hel" to find "hell" and "hello" before "aaaanother hellish stuff". (the larger the data, the better it is to query the db often). If you want to query the db once, the best way is to do it before the autocompletion. Put the result in an array or object, and set it as the source of your autocompletion. The plugin will filter on the typed text anyway.

Comment: yes roselan, i was intending to populate the options with json or arrays anyway, i did include it in the post title, but clearly that wasnt obvious!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out jQuery UI Autocomplete and the examples there?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

That should help you out with the "search as you type" part.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
$("#text").keyup(function() {
    var input = $("#text").val();
    $.post("someurl/myService.cgi", {
        searchTerm: input
    },
    function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            $("#list").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
        });
    },
    'json'
});
```

You should do some validation on the input before you post data to the server though. It might also be an idea to cache some of the search results with $.data() unless it piles up too much, to avoid too many server hits. You can use `$("#list").empty()` to remove all items from the suggestion list between searches.

Comment: thanks, but i need to use .html() as there wil ALWAYS be 9 li there for design reasons

Comment: Just wanted to point you in the right direction, and figured you'd take it from there. Might be easier to look into some of the other solutions posted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

There is an example on that page that brings down results from db based on what you type. I assume you can take it from there (get the clicked item and add it to your page/block).
I hope I understood your question right.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#list').hide();
    $("#find").click(function(){
        $('#list').toggle();
    });
    $('#find').bind('keyup', function(){
        $('ul#list li').css({display : 'none'});
        $('#list li').each(function(){
            var e = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if (e.indexOf($('#find').val().toLowerCase()) != -1){
                $(this).css({display : 'block'});
            }
        });
    });
});
```

replace your js with this. it will populate the ul as you type. NOTE: to see it work make sure you make it all the way to item 2 since it matches characters you will see all 3 results until you have a character that does not match any of them.

Answer (score 0):

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QW7Bc/3/) for the lazy student. (ahhh the good old times ^^)